# How to get asset file path in Xamarin?

Tags: android, file, xamarin, xamarin.android, assets

I have `data.xlsx` file in `Assets` folder and need to get its path to apply some library.

Found several solutions here but neither works for me. For example -
[File Not Found Exception In Xamarin program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775060/file-not-found-exception-in-xamarin-program)

I tried to use `file:///android_asset/data.xlsx` but here is no file too.

I checked the path with: `System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);`

So how to get path to this file? Maybe I have to place it in different folder?

**Update**: possibly I can solve it this way: [java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor/33359656#33359656)

But I can't find where to place it.

**Update**: this question is about Java and this is unclear how to use this solution in Xamarin.Android: [How to get the android Path string to a file on Assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder)

Comment: try to use * file://android_asset/data.xlsx * instead of *file:///android_asset/data.xlsx*

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi, same result.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474821/how-to-get-the-android-path-string-to-a-file-on-assets-folder

Comment: Does your library not have an overload that has a stream as parameter instead of a filename?

Comment: @InfernumDeus If the library does not accept a `Stream` and only a file-based `Uri`, then copy the file, via an Asset stream, from your app bundle to a local dir (CacheDir, etc...) and pass that file path to your library method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's impossible.

Closest solution is to write file to Cache.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the file isn't included in the APK. Ensure that the *Build Action* of the file in the Asset-folder is set to *AndroidAsset*.

Comment: Good point but yes, it was automatically set to AndroidAsset.

Comment: Do you get a valid stream if you open the asset via a the AssetManager?

Answer (score 1):

in general using Xamarin.android , you can use this code :

```
private string _fileName {get;set;}

      public string FileFullPath
      {
         get
          {
            return Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures),_fileName);
          }
      }
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Can i somehow refer to any different directory than `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures`? My file is input data so this sounds a bit inappropriate.

Comment: `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is now deprecated